# How to download attachment from gmail in C# using IMAP?

Tags: c#, .net, imap

I have  using a console app for downloading document from the mail using IMAP Service. I use "S22.Imap" assembly in application for the IMAP. I got the all mails contains attached files in IEnumerable. How could I download these Files?

```
using (ImapClient client = new ImapClient(hostname, 993, username, password, AuthMethod.Login, true))
        {
            IEnumerable<uint> uids = client.Search(SearchCondition.Subject("Attachments"));
            IEnumerable<MailMessage> messages = client.GetMessages(uids,
                (Bodypart part) =>
                {
                    if (part.Disposition.Type == ContentDispositionType.Attachment)
                    {
                        if (part.Type == ContentType.Application &&
                           part.Subtype == "VND.MS-EXCEL")
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            );
       }
```

[image]

I would appreciate it, if you give a solution

Comment: At the screenshot, expand Base and you should get [ContentStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.Mail.Attachment%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The attachments type has a property on it called `ContentStream` you can see this on the msdn documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.attachment(v=vs.110).aspx.

Using that you can use something like this to then save the file:

```
using (var fileStream = File.Create("C:\\Folder"))
{
    part.ContentStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    part.ContentStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
}
```

Edit:
So after `GetMessages` is done you could do:

```
foreach(var msg in messages)
{
    foreach (var attachment in msg.Attachments)
    {
        using (var fileStream = File.Create("C:\\Folder"))
        {
            attachment.ContentStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            attachment.ContentStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best source will be the documentation http://smiley22.github.io/S22.Imap/Documentation/

Comment: It is indeed. The OP should check the examples  like [this one](http://smiley22.github.io/S22.Imap/Documentation/html/f76134df-07a8-4dd6-8a14-4ad00db062fb.htm)

Answer (score 0):

see this link is about download attachments from email

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Fetch-and-read-email-messages-with-attachments-from-GMAIL-POP3-mail-server-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: The OP is asking about using IMAP and a specific library. The link you posted is about POP

Answer (score 0):

```
messages.Attachments.Download();
messages.Attachments.Save("location", fileSaveName)
```

this way you can download attachment in email using IMAP

Answer (score 0):

This code will store attachment file inside c drive in Download folder    .

```
 foreach (var msg in messages)

                        {
                             foreach (var attachment in msg.Attachments)
                            {

                                byte[] allBytes = new byte[attachment.ContentStream.Length];
                                int bytesRead = attachment.ContentStream.Read(allBytes, 0, (int)attachment.ContentStream.Length);

                                string destinationFile = @"C:\Download\" + attachment.Name;

                                BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(destinationFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None));
                                writer.Write(allBytes);
                                writer.Close();
                            }

                }
```

Hope help to someone