# Mail attachments downloading in any mail server through programming

Tags: c#, .net, email

What I am trying to achieve is to download mail attachments of particular type from Gmail or Yahoo or any other server through code. Is it possible or any idea regarding this will be of great help

Comment: Connect through POP or IMAP, iterate over the mails, check if they have attachtments. What have you tried and what is your question exactly?

Comment: The mail servers are webpages and you have to write custom code to interface with each webpage.

Comment: through the class name property of the attachment in the mail i am able to click that attachment,but it has two problems one if the mail is opened in IE then after clicking a pop up opens showing two options SAVE and CANCEL which i can't click through code since it is a security feature of Microsoft.the other problem is that i want to download only a particular type of mail and clicking the class name will download each attachment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like below code:

```
using(Pop3 pop3 = new Pop3())  
 {  
     pop3.Connect("server");  
     pop3.UseBestLogin("user", "password");  
     foreach (string uid in pop3.GetAll())  
     {  
         IMail email = new MailBuilder()
         .CreateFromEml(pop3.GetMessageByUID(uid));  
         Console.WriteLine(email.Subject);  
         // save all attachments to disk  
         email.Attachments.ForEach(mime => mime.Save(mime.SafeFileName));  
     }  
     pop3.Close();  
 }
```

Source:

1) https://www.limilabs.com/blog/download-email-attachments-net

2) http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/188349/Read-Gmail-Inbox-Message-in-ASP-NET

Hope this will helps you.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need IMAP for this. You will be required to first read the MIME of the mail. Then you can easily download the attachment if its present.

In POP there is no provision to know if the mail has attachment in it. In POP you will be required to download complete mail locally and then parse the MIME of mail.

In C# there are classes which can decipher/parse the MIME structure of mail and can provide easy access to various parts of mail.

[How to download attachment from gmail in C# using IMAP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31787037/how-to-download-attachment-from-gmail-in-c-sharp-using-imap)